# Problema de margin quando gera de pdf

Tags: c#, mvc, rotativa

Estou fazendo um relatório, quando to gerando o pdf, tentei implementa a margem, mas continua a corta a tabela no meio e continua na outra pagina.

Está acontecendo isso na margem, mesmo eu colocando ele continua a corta no meio da tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é minha controller onde gera o pdf:

```
var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
            {
                ViewName = "TesteRelatorio",
                PageSize = Size.A4,
                IsGrayScale = true,
                Model = abastecimento.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, abastecimento.Count),
            };
            return pdf;
```

Minha View:

```
    @using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento>

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Relatório de Vendas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml"; }
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>Relatório Venda por Pedido/Período De: @ViewBag.dataInicio á @ViewBag.dataFinal </b></h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">

                <table id="customers">

                    <tr>
                        <th>Quant. Total (Litros):</th>
                        <th>Total (R$):</th>
                        <th>Total de Km Percorrido:</th>
                        <th>Media de Litro Consumido:</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.Sum(t => t.Litro)</td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.TotalGasto</td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.Total</td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.KmMedia</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="print">
                    <table id="customers">

                        <tr>

                            <th>N° Carro </th>
                            <th>Quant. </th>
                            <th>Km </th>
                            <th>Valor Unitário </th>
                            <th>Sub Total </th>
                            <th>Data Abastecimento </th>
                        </tr>
                        @{foreach (var item in Model)
                            {

                                <tr>
                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumCarro.NCarro) </td>
                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Litro) </td>
                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Km) </td>
                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VlrUnit) </td>
                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalGasto) </td>
                                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtAbastecido) </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Layout2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

`Ribeira`

```
</nav>
<header>
    <h1>
        Ribeira Beer Distribuidora de Bebidas Ltda
    </h1>
</header>
<div class="print">
    <div class="conteudo">
        <main>
            @RenderBody()
        </main>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="page-break">
    <footer>
        Copyright 2017 - RibeiraBeer
    </footer>
</div>
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

Meu CSS:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah);




html{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    /* Altura 480 px  largura: 1920 */
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    background-image: url(../Imagens/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: 4em;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

nav a {
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    margin-right: 1em;
    display:inline-block;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 1em;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}


main{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

aside {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: white;
}
div.static {
    position: static;
    }
footer{
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #31385a;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    page-break-after: auto;
}


article {
    background-color:white;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: Merriweather, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

.blog-post-meta{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    color: #AAA;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height:1em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
}


article + article {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.conteudo{
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #333;
}


aside ul {
    padding: 0;
}
aside li{
    list-style:none;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
tbody tr:hover{
    background-color: #EEE;
}
tr + tr {
    border-top:1px solid #CCC;
}
td {
    padding: .5em;
}

td a:before{
    font-size: 20px;
}
td a{
    font-size: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
th{
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    margin-top: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    color: #666;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    width: 1.25em;
    height: 1.25em;
    display: block;
}

[type=text],[type=password],textarea, select{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:20%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: .5em;
}

input[type=submit]{
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color:#31385a;
    border: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border-color: red;
    background-color: #ffced2;
}

.field-validation-error, .field-validation-valid{
    color: red;
    display: block;
    margin-top: .5em;
}

@media (min-width: 50em){
    .conteudo {
        width: 50em;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    main{
        float: left;
        width: 35em;
    }
    aside {
        width: 12em;
        float: right;
    }
    td a {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    background-color: #294a73;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
#customers2 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers2 td, #customers2 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers2 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers2 tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #3e4e84;
    color: white;
}

#customers2 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

@media print {

    * { 
        background: transparent !important; 
        color: #000 !important; 
        text-shadow: none !important; 
        filter:none !important; 
        -ms-filter: none !important; 
    } 

    body {
        margin:0; 
        padding:0;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        font: 12pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        color: #000;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 1.5cm;
    }

    .wrap { 
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0; 
        float: none !important; 
    }

    .no-print, nav, footer, video, audio, object, embed { 
        display:none; 
    }

    .print {
        display: block;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    aside {
        display:block;
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 24pt;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 18pt;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 14pt;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 12pt;
        widows: 3;
        orphans: 3;
    }

    a, a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a:link:after, a:visited:after { 
        content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
    }

    p a {
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    q:after {
        content: " (" attr(cite) ")"
    }

    a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { 
        content: ""; 
    }  

    .page-break { 
        page-break-before: always; 
    }

    /*Estilos da Demo*/
    .header.print h1{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
        font-size: 18pt;
    }

    .header.print:after {
        content: "Bem vindo";
    }

    .artigo {
        margin-top: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        padding-top: 1cm;
    }

    h1 a:link:after, h1 a:visited:after { 
        content: ""; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenta colocar margin   PageMargins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Tentei colocar as margens em tudo 0, e continua a corta a tabela ao meio

Comment: Não tem nenhum estilo na view?

Comment: To aplicando o meu layout, vou coloca o codigo na pergunta

Comment: @PauloHDSousa coloquei o layout e a view do pdf

Comment: Tem algum .css externo? na Master ou algo assim?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Tem um css, quer que eu posto todo ele?

Comment: Sim, acho que nele que está as margens

Comment: Tenta Tirar TODOS os css e gerar o PDF

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Retirei todo Css e o relatorio não corta mais a tabela no meio

Comment: então tem algo no css

Comment: @PauloHDSousa poderia coloca isso como resposta para eu pode positivar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem algo no .css que está quebrando na geração do seu PDF.